# magento 2.0 How to get associated products of a grouped product in product list page

Tags: magento-2.0, grouped-products, associate-products

I want to show all associated products of a grouped product in product list page.

I have made a category Brand in that I assigned all grouped products. In listing page, I displayed all brands as a list view.

Now I want to show all associated products of each group product on this listing page. I can get associated products of a grouped product in view page for an individual product.

How can I use grouped product module in list page as I could use it in product view page?